# How to add data that sequentially increases by 1 by adding a new column to existing data using Python

Tags: mysql, sql, pymysql

Using Python, I am trying to put data that is sequentially incremented by 1 in the newly added 'legendary' column to the existing data.

There are hundreds of thousands of data, but when I try to put non-duplicate data that increases by 1 in the formula 1,2,3... in the new 'legendary' column, I want to write a query statement using a while statement. Do I need to write

This is the query I tried.

```
import pymysql

conn=pymysql.connect(
user='rt',
passwd='1520*',
host='127.0.0.1',
db='prtice',
charset='utf8')

curs = conn.cursor()

num = 0
while num >= 1:
    num += 1
    sql = "update juso set legendary = %s"
    value = 'num'
    if num == 100000:
        break
    curs.execute(sql, value)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Can u add ur sql create class statement ?

Comment: you can make **legendary auto-increment primary key** that fulfills your requirement. Please make sure **auto_increment_offset** & **auto_increment_increment** are set 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your legendary column auto increment by one using the create table function, there will be no need to increment the value from your py code each time. And also the query you tried to set the value to num as a string, so each time the legendary column will store num as value.

Comment: Is it impossible to insert a number that increases by 1 per data by creating only a column in the existing data without creating a table?

Comment: if you want a temp fix for the existing data , you can just create the column and use a stored procedure to update the value. you can use a cursor to loop through your rows. Just look for cursor in stored procedures.